# Please explain below jquery lines

Tags: jquery, html

Kindly explain the meaning of below listed code of line of jquery.

```
$('body > *:not(style, script)').trigger('add.cards');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets the all elements inside the `body` (1 level, only children) except `styles` and `scripts`. Then it assumes that there is an `custom event` with the name '`add.card`' and triggers it.
Trigger - call the callback for the event .

**$('body')** - gets the body element.
**$('body > *')** - gets all direct children in the body.
**$('body > *:not(style, script)')** - gets all direct children in the body except styles and scripts.
**$('body > *:not(style, script)').trigger('add.cards')** - gets all direct children in the body except styles and scripts and execute the callback for the 'add.cards' custom event.

Answer (score 1):

The code selects all elements within the `body` tag, except `<style>` and `<script>` and triggers an `add` event on them, with the namespace of `cards`.

Answer (score 1):

> indicates direct children of body
>   :not is a selector that excludes items mentioned in (). Here they are 'style' and 'script'
>   .trigger - runs events defined on it

Answer (score 0):

Select *(All) child elements in the body tag which will :not(not,exclusion) be style and script and then trigger add.cards event/function on selected elements.